# Suitescript, nlapiRequestURL, can't turn a JSON from a URL into an object/array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, netsuite, suitescript

In netsuite i'm using the `nlapiRequestURL` to retrieve a JSON data from flexport, an overseas shipping company. I have have the data as a string(to my knowledge retrieving json data makes it a string) and want to turn it into an array of objects, but everything I have tried has resulted in various errors.

trying...

```
       `var output = nlapiRequestURL(url,null,headers,"GET");
        var split = JSON.parse(output.getBody());
        response.write(split);`
```

gave me
`{records=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7220fad}`
and trying to show any element of split gave me undefined or that it cant read element from index.
I've ran the string through a JSON checker and it said it was a valid JSON file. I've done various variations of JSON.parse and looked tried Tostring. I've been working on this for a while and have no idea why I can't parse this information properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you also add the JSON string you're parsing?

Comment: I can add a snipit if you think it will help, but the string itself if 29 pages total.

Comment: Yes just a snippet is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parsed the result but then you are writing the parsed object which just gets you the object’s implementation dependent toString() output.

If you are just trying to echo the response re-stringify the parsed payload.

Comment: Doing that returns it as a string again. I'm not entirely familiar with JSON, but to my understanding when I retrieve JSON data it turns it into a string, then with JSON.parse it would take that JSON string and turn it into an array/object. So if i did something like   `response.write(split.flex_id[1]);` It would return the ID of the second item in the array. Instead I get  `TypeError Cannot read property "1" from undefined.`  
What would I need to do to take this JSON string and turn it into an Array?

Comment: What for? You have parsed it. If you wrote `response.write(split.records.length);`  you'd see the size of the array that the records property references. So if you want an id, just from what you've pasted so far, you'd write `response.write(split.records[0].flex_id)`

Comment: So adding the   `.records` was able to show me the field that I wanted. Thanks!!! What does `.records` do? I haven't heard of it before, and from general searching I haven't found anything on it besides get examples in suitescript documentation

Comment: `.records` has nothing to do with JSON nor Netsuite. It is part of the object returned from your call to flexport. It's listed in their [API docs](https://apidocs.flexport.com/#shipments).